# How to directly write to Http OutputStream using Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I created an endpoint that should offer a file for download.
The endpoint itself has to fetch the download file from another external web endpoint. My endpoint is thus some kind of proxy for the download.

For not having to read the entire file into my memory (as files may be quite large), I'd like to directly write them into the response stream of my endpoint users.

If I'd be using `RestTemplate`, I could achieve this as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download")
public void download(HttpServletResponse response) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());

    restTemplate.execute(
        fileToDownloadUri,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        responseExtractor -> {
            IOUtils.copy(responseExtractor.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
            return null;
        });
}
```

BUT: I'd like to use the `WebClient` class. How could I achieve the same?

```
webClient.get().uri(fileToDownloadUri). //what now?
```

Comment: since you are using restTemplate it is blocking and the api you are calling will probably return the full file, so you can't "stream" it. You are in your example copying the full body just over till the outputstream and the response vill get it also blocking.

i have no experience here, but maybe try doing `.flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(ByteBuffer.class)`

Comment: Well but still, if I try the `RestTemplate` version, the file is not loaded into memory before the file is transfered to the client, but it is just copied through! The download for the client starts directly from clients perspective. And that's what I want to achieve the same with webclient.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream) `This method buffers the input internally` so so the entire file is loaded into memory and then it is copied from one stream into another. So i have no idea what you are talking about.